# How to delete all comments from XML using XQuery on SQL Server 2005?

Tags: xml, xquery

I can easily select all comments from XML by

```
select @XML.query('comment()')
```

but can't find how to delete them. Is there appropriate syntax for  @XML.modify('delete ...')?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```xquery
set @XML.modify('delete comment()')
select @XML
```

Here it is.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this article provides you the solution
[Improving XML Update Performance with SQL Server 2005](http://www.15seconds.com/issue/050818.htm)

```xquery
UPDATE Store SET Demographics.modify('delete //newnode') WHERE CustomerID = @custid
```